# Solr: Remove Double Quote Characters from a Field

Tags: java, regex, solr

Some of our documents have double quote characters in them and that can break some searches on those documents. How do I set up the PatternReplaceCharFilterFactory to remove double quote characters? I tried various escape characters but to no avail, e.g.:

`<charFilter class="solr.PatternReplaceCharFilterFactory" pattern="[;:\'\"\\*/\),\(\-]" replacement=" "/>`

Does not appear to work as the core won't load with a schema parsing error.

Answer (score 1):

Apparently as the schema.xml is XML, then I need to use the special XML token `&quot;`